# What is the behavior of a Chrome extension notification (chrome.notifications) shown with priority < 0?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It appears to me that something like this:

```
var message = 'Hello world!';
var title = 'Hello world!';
var notificationOptions = {
  type: 'basic',
  title: title,
  message: message,
  iconUrl: chrome.extension.getURL('assets/images/icon-32.png'),
  priority: -1
};
chrome.notifications.create(
  'my_notification',
  'my_notification_id',
  notificationOptions,
  function() {}
);
```

will never be shown. The reason is the priority: -1. So what do negative priorities really mean and how are they displayed in chrome notifications?

Comment: By "It appears to me... will never be shown" do you mean you've tested it and observed the behavior, or that's what you expect will happen?

Comment: That is what I have tested and observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never shown *as a toast*.

Instead, it goes straight into the Notifications list in the systray. Normal (priority >= 0) notifications disappear off screen after a few seconds and are also added to that list.

The only alert the user gets is that the bell icon lights up.

I am not sure what is the difference between priority -1 and -2. At a minimum it affects the ordering of the notifications, but possibly -2 also does not make the Notifications icon active. Needs testing -the documentation is very lacking.

Comment: Interesting. Where do they go on OS X? I don't see anything in the OS's notification pane.

Comment: It is not integrated in OS-level notification centers, it's independent. Look at the indicators area.

Comment: That's right. I found a "bell" icon in my OS X "tray" (the area to the left of the time) and there it was, my -1 notification! Thanks!